# Google App Engine (GAE) WEB-INF/lib order

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jar, mqtt

Hey guys i'm working on a project with Google App Engine. To get Data from my devices we're using MQTT. The org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.* library starts a Thread with "client.connect()".
After some researches i found that you cant just simply create Threads when working with GAE. Following error is shown:
**java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")**

So i continued searching and someone told to use following code instead of a "normal" Thread:

**Thread monitoringThread = ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest( new Runnable() {..}**

So i decompiled the paho library, looked up where the Thread is created and changed it.
I created a new class exported it as mymqttclient.jar
In eclipse i changed the order of my build at Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export so mymqttclient.jar is loaded before the mqtt-client-0.4.0.jar So that it will use my created function with the monitoringThread.

But how can i change the order of the .jar's in the web-inf/lib ?

Thank you very much for your answers, i couldnt find something useful until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is no need to decompile any of the Paho code it is all available from [here](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/).

Since you can now get the clean source, why not just modify the original class and rebuild the jar file, then you don't need to worry about messing with the Classpath to get your class to load first?